# Find out if you can post to users wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently toying with the Facebook Graph Api and have been able to get some interesting results, I would like to be able to post to one of my Facebook App users pages. They have authenticated the app and confirmed the ability for my app to be able to post on there wall. I know there is the can_post check using FQL, but I haven't seen any information on this using the Graph API. Is there a possible check to make so I can see if I have the ability to post on there wall?

**can_post**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Answer (score 0):

This settings is actually a setting of the timeline:

[image]

This setting only affects the *viewers* of the specific timeline and does not apply to the owner of the timeline.

> `can_post` - **`bool`** - Whether or not the viewer can post to the user's Wall

Beyond this settings, by authenticating an application and giving it certain publishing permissions, the application, using it's **per-user per-app** access token will be able to perform actions on behalf the actual user. Actions will be attributed to the user even though it is the application that initiated and published these stories.

---

To answer what I assume is your underlying question - your application, given the appropriate permissions, will *always* be able able to publish a story to the users timeline. The act of giving an application any permissions is the same as allowing the application to act *as you* and access everything you would be able to access. This includes posting a story to your own timeline (even if no other **user** would be able to).

Comment: Sorry I don't think I have explain it right, I have found out the answer as I didn't realise I could call /me/permissions on the Facebook Graph Api and there I can find out if the 'publish_actions' is set.